# Access SparkConf from the worker

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to get spark configurations from the worker (i.e. inside the closure of a map function). I tried using

```
SparkEnv.get().conf()
```

but it seems to not contain all the custom spark configs that I've set prior to creating SparkContext

EDIT:

Through SparkEnv I'm able to get default configurations set via `spark-defaults.config` but all confs I set explicitly through the setter method

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("my.configuration.key", "myConfigValue")
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

are not present in the `SparkConf` object I get through `SparkEnv.get().conf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparkEnv` is a part of the developer API and is [not intended for external use](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkEnv).

You can simply create a broadcast variable, though.

```
val confBd = sc.broadcast(sc.getConf.getAll.toMap)
rdd.foreachPartition(_ => println(confBd.value.get("spark.driver.host")))
```